# Python SFTP File Not Found Errors

Tags: python, ftp, sftp

I'm attempting to download all the files in an SFTP directory to a local folder using the `pysftp` library. My code looks like this:

```
import pysftp

sftp = pysftp.Connection('server', username = 'name', password = 'password')

sftp.get_d('Daily_Reports', '/home/jchrysostom/Documents/SupplyChain/Daily_Reports/')
```

`Daily_Reports` is a folder that exists on the SFTP server - I have verified this. I have also verified that `/home/jchrysostom/Documents/SupplyChain/Daily_Reports/` exists. I can `cd` to it in terminal with no problems.

However, when I run this python script, I get the following error: `IOError: [Errno 2] File not found.`

Any ideas what may be causing this?

UPDATE: A little investigation shows that the files actually *have* downloaded. In fact, all of them have downloaded just fine. However, I'm unable to run the rest of the script, because it's erroring out for some reason. Is this just a bug in the library?

UPDATE 2 - Full Traceback, as requested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "supplychain.py", line 20, in <module>
    sftp.get_d('Daily_Reports','/home/jchrysostom/Documents/SupplyChain/Daily_Reports/')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysftp.py", line 255, in get_d
    preserve_mtime=preserve_mtime)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysftp.py", line 497, in cd
    self.cwd(original_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysftp.py", line 510, in chdir
    self._sftp.chdir(remotepath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 580, in chdir
    if not stat.S_ISDIR(self.stat(path).st_mode):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 413, in stat
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_STAT, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 729, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 776, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 802, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)
IOError: [Errno 2] File not found
```

Comment: can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Yep. Just added it for you.

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can tell, this is a bug in `pysftp`. The files are being copied successfully, but (at least according to the traceback here) the library is blowing up when it tries to change back to the original remote working directory on the FTP server.

Workaround is to iterate over the files in the directory and `get()` each individually...

```
for filename in sftp.listdir('Daily_Reports'):
    sftp.get('Daily_Reports/' + filename, localpath = '/home/jchrysostom/Documents/SupplyChain/Daily_Reports/' + filename)
```

Comment: Is this still an issue with the library?